# Create CSV file with randomised filepaths in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, filepath

I have lots of csv files including data from simulations I make. I feed them to a deep learning algorithm by putting all simulation output csv files as a file paths in another single csv file. However, I need two csv files, one of them consisting 20% of the output csv file paths and the other containing the remaining 80%. I have an algorithm to do it but it isn't randomised;

```
with open('C:\\train.csv', 'w') as outf:

  print('x:data,y:label', file=outf)

  for i in range(80):
      print('./1/a_%s.csv, 1' % (i + 21), file=outf)

with open('C:\\test.csv', 'w') as outf:

  print('x:data,y:label', file=outf)

  for i in range(20):
      print('./1/a_%s.csv, 1' % (i + 1), file=outf)
```

When I do it like this, I get files 1-20 in one of the csv files and from 21 to 100 in the other one. However, I want them to be randomised. so maybe if I have total of 10 samples, have 3 and 7 (random) in one file, and the remaining ones in the other one. Is there a way that I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try making the array of indices and shuffle them first. Then use the first 80 indices for first CSV and rest (20) for the second:

```
from random import shuffle    

indices = list(range(1,101))
shuffle(indices)

with open('C:\\train.csv', 'w') as outf:
    print('x:data,y:label', file=outf)

    for i in indices[:80]:
        print('./1/a_%s.csv, 1' % i, file=outf)

with open('C:\\test.csv', 'w') as outf:
    print('x:data,y:label', file=outf)

    for i in indices[80:]:
        print('./1/a_%s.csv, 1' % i, file=outf)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem in machine learning. [`scikit-learn`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) has [several tools](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.model_selection) for dealing with this, e.g. [`train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

indices = list(range(1, 101))
i_a, i_b = train_test_split(indices, train_size=0.8, test_size=0.2)
```

Now you can iterate over `i_a` (80 random indices) and `i_b` (20 random indices) as in your original code:

```
with open('C:\\train.csv', 'w') as outf:
    print('x:data,y:label', file=outf)

    for i in i_a:
        print('./1/a_%s.csv, 1' % i, file=outf)

with open('C:\\test.csv', 'w') as outf:
    print('x:data,y:label', file=outf)

    for i in i_b:
        print('./1/a_%s.csv, 1' % i, file=outf)
```